# is it possible to show AdMob banner in android 2.3.3?

Tags: android, admob

I know using admob banner needs to add tag:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

and I tried compile with 4.0.3, it can show the banner, but I try to set sdks as 2.3.3,it does not compile because it does not support

```
    screenSize|smallestScreenSize
```

but if I change it to

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode"
```

it can compile but cannot show the banner and it shows "Missing AdActivity with..." in the banner position,it seems the banner require the whole string

```
keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize
```

is it possible to show the admob banner in android 2.3.3?

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you set your minSdk to 8, but targetSdk to the latest one that you want in your manifest file

```
minSdkVersion=8
```